# How to send real-time sensor data from wear os to mobile?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am currently working on an android application where I would like to first gather sensor data form a smartwatch and continuously send that data into the handheld device. Most of the documentation I have seen generally uses a button to send data, how can I do this without the use of a button and have the data streamed in real time?

Right now, I am using the health services api to extract the heart rate but I'm not really sure how to properly pair this with a message or channel client to constantly send the data every time there's a change. I've read that using DataItems helps synchronize data between both devices whenever there is a change, but I haven't found any documentation that points me the correct way of implementing it to my project.

I am new to java and android development so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer) documentation is a good entry point